# Can I find the "dot product" of 3 vectors using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a code to use Simpson's rule for integration. As the process of Simpson integration is very similar to taking the dot product of 2 vectors, I used `np.dot` in my project. The problem is that I need to write another "uglier" code consisting of multiple `for` loops if I want to find the "dot product" of 3 vectors because I have all my data saved inside multiple 2D arrays. What I mean is for vectors

```
A = [1, 3, 5] 
B = [2, 1, 5]
C = [5, 8, 6]
```

I want the result to be 1x2x5 + 3x1x8 + 5x5x6 = 184  which would hypothetically be

```
result = np.dot(A, B, C)
```

What I am looking for is a function for the process I mentioned above.

Comment: "would hypothetically be `np.dot`" not exactly... from [Math World](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html): "The associative property is meaningless for the dot product because (**a** · **b** ) · **c** is not defined since **a** · **b** is a scalar and therefore cannot itself be dotted."

Comment: @Aaron also `dot` is not commutative, unlike this operation.

Comment: The dot product has a clear mathematical meaning as a function from 2 Vectors to 1 scalar. What you want is not the dot product at all, it's just an operation that looks a bit similar. (and looking at Simpson's rule, I am honestly unsure where you want to use this)

Comment: @mozway dot is in fact commutative.

Comment: @MegaIng `a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) ; b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) ; print(a@b , b@a)`, but I agree not if you stick to 1D arrays ;)

Comment: @mozway dot is not exactly the same as GEMM https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354047/dot-product-versus-matrix-multiplication-is-the-later-a-special-case-of-the-fir

Answer (score 4):

Simply multiply the arrays element-wise and compute the sum of the resulting array:

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 5])
b = np.array([2, 1, 5])
c = np.array([5, 8, 6])

>>> a * b * c
array([ 10,  24, 150])

>>> np.sum(a * b * c)
184
```

Comment: While this works for this specific case, it's not a general a solution as using `np.prod` or `np.multiply.reduce`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.multiply.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), then [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
np.multiply.reduce([A, B, C]).sum()
```

Output: `184`

As a function:

```
def sum_prod(*args):
    return np.multiply.reduce(args).sum()

sum_prod(A, B, C)
# 184
```

*NB. this also works if `A`/`B`/`C` are lists.*

Comment: `multi_dot` may not be the best name since that risks confusion with numpy's [`numpy.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html), which behaves differently.

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes, that's true and it's also not really a reduced dot product, I changed the name

Answer (score 2):

directly use `np.prod`

```
np.prod([A, B, C], 0).sum()
184
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = [1, 3, 5] 
B = [2, 1, 5]
C = [5, 8, 6]

np.prod([A,B,C],axis=0).sum()
```

This will fix your problem.

Here, your numbers are multiplied along 'axis = 0', there by you will get

[10 24 150]

Sum of this array is then calculated, thus output is 184.

Hope this fixed your issue!